# How to collect stats from within scrapy spider callback?

Tags: python, scrapy

How can I collect stats from within a spider callback?

**Example**

```
class MySpider(Spider):
     name = "myspider"
     start_urls = ["http://example.com"]

def parse(self, response):
    stats.set_value('foo', 'bar')
```

Not sure what to `import` or how to make `stats` available in general.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out the [stats page from the scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html). The documentation states that the Stats Collector, but it may be necessary to add `from scrapy.stats import stats` to your spider code to be able to do stuff with it.

EDIT: At the risk of blowing my own trumpet,  if you were after a concrete example I posted an [answer about how to collect failed urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724730/how-to-get-the-scrapy-failure-urls/13799984#13799984).

EDIT2: After a lot of googling, apparently no imports are necessary. Just use `self.crawler.stats.set_value()`!

Comment: hmm. it returns ``ImportError: cannot import name crawler``. ``File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/stats.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scrapy.project import crawler``

Comment: That's odd. I take it that your basic spider works without error?

Comment: yep. it works as long as I don't do anything with ``stats``. here is an example of how my spider looks like: https://gist.github.com/mattes/10367042

Comment: I've edited my answer above. You can just use `self.crawler.stats.set_value()` in the `parse` method.

Comment: How do you reference the stats that were collected in a crawl?

Answer (score 3):

With [scrapy 0.24 - stats](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/stats.html#common-stats-collector-uses) I use it by the follow way:

```
class TopSearchesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "topSearches"
    allowed_domains = ["...domain..."]

    start_urls = (
        'http://...domain...',
    )

    def __init__(self, stats):
        super(TopSearchesSpider, self).__init__()
        self.stats = stats

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.stats)

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response);
        url = response.url;

        self.stats.inc_value('pages_crawled')
        ...
```

***super*** method is to call CrawlSpider constructor to execute its own code.

Answer (score 2):

Add this inside your spider class

```
def my_parse(self, response): 
    print self.crawler.stats.get_stats()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use in other, you can:

> spider.crawler.stats.get_stats()

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the scrapy stats after crawling as python object. This might help -

```html
def spider_results(spider):
    results = []
    stats = []

    def crawler_results(signal, sender, item, response, spider):
        results.append(item)

    def crawler_stats(*args, **kwargs):
        stats.append(kwargs['sender'].stats.get_stats())

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal=signals.item_scraped)

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_stats, signal=signals.spider_closed)

    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(spider) # put our own spider class here
    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
    return results, stats
```

Hope it helps!