# Finding top 5 common words in a website using scrapy framework

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I can find out top 5 common words without [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) by fetching pages content and finding text form page. Then dumping words in dictionary with count of appearing.

But I want to utilise facility of scrapy to do this. But I am not sure where should I keep that dictionary in project to hold word count so spider can send data to common place then to update that dictionary.

How can I use scrapy to find top common words?
Can I use stat collection module of scrapy so after completion of crawling I can print in stats?

Comment: yes, stats is the place.

Comment: How can I send words to stat module?

Comment: If the question is about "how to write stats in scrapy", then I don't see the point of asking about "top common words on a website". About stats, here is some [useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951418/how-to-collect-stats-from-within-scrapy-spider-callback)

Comment: This not about writing stats in scrapy, Its about solving this problem with scrapy itself. Using scrapy there can be multiple approach and stat can be one of them that I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used scrapy before, but I think I have a solution for counting all the words in the text of the body of HTML.

In a file named `words_spider.py` put the following code:

```
from collections import Counter

import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for text in response.xpath('//body//*//text()').extract():
            # Eliminate empty strings
            words_ = (item.strip() for item in text.strip().split(' '))
            words = [item for item in words_ if item]
            if any(words):
                yield Counter(words)
```

Then in another file named `scrapy_runner.py` put the following code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import shlex
import json
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

FILENAME = 'counters.json'
SCRIPTNAME = 'words_spider.py'

try:
    os.remove(FILENAME)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass # No file to remove
# Run the spider.
subprocess.check_call(shlex.split(f'scrapy runspider {SCRIPTNAME} -o {FILENAME}'))

with open(FILENAME) as fh:
    # Create counters out of saved JSON file.
    counts = (Counter(item) for item in json.load(fh))

# Add all the counters together.
pprint(reduce(add, counts), indent=4)
```

Run the script: `python scrapy_runner.py`:

The output is:

> Counter({   'humor': 12,
>               'by': 11,
>               '(about)': 10,
>               'Tags:': 10,
>               'a': 7,
>               'you': 7,
>               'to': 6,
>               'in': 6,
>               'and': 6,
>               'is': 5,
>               'think': 5,
>               'the': 4,
>               '“The': 3,
>               'be': 3,
>               'must': 3,
>               'can': 3,
>               'Quotes': 2,
>               'it': 2,
>               'or': 2,
>               'who': 2,
>               'books': 2,
>               'simile': 2,
>               'thinks': 2,
>               'sitting': 2,
>               'make': 2,
>               'that': 2,
>               'of': 2,
>               'beholder': 2,
>               'time': 2,
>               'chocolate': 2,
>               'Charles': 2,
>               'right': 2,
>               'it.”': 2,
>               'people': 2,
>               'with': 2,
>               'only': 2,
>               'I': 2,
>               'truth': 2,
>               'Scrape': 1,
>               'Login': 1,
>               'Viewing': 1,
>               'tag:': 1,
>               'person,': 1,
>               'gentleman': 1,
>               'lady,': 1,
>               'has': 1,
>               'not': 1,
>               'pleasure': 1,
>               'good': 1,
>               'novel,': 1,
>               'intolerably': 1,
>               'stupid.”': 1,
>               'Jane': 1,
>               'Austen': 1,
>               'aliteracy': 1,
>               'classic': 1,
>               '“A': 1,
>               'day': 1,
>               'without': 1,
>               'sunshine': 1,
>               'like,': 1,
>               'know,': 1,
>               'night.”': 1,
>               'Steve': 1,
>               'Martin': 1,
>               'obvious': 1,
>               '“Anyone': 1,
>               'church': 1,
>               'Christian': 1,
>               'also': 1,
>               'garage': 1,
>               'car.”': 1,
>               'Garrison': 1,
>               'Keillor': 1,
>               'religion': 1,
>               '“Beauty': 1,
>               'eye': 1,
>               'may': 1,
>               'necessary': 1,
>               'from': 1,
>               'give': 1,
>               'stupid': 1,
>               'misinformed': 1,
>               'black': 1,
>               'eye.”': 1,
>               'Jim': 1,
>               'Henson': 1,
>               '“All': 1,
>               'need': 1,
>               'love.': 1,
>               'But': 1,
>               'little': 1,
>               'now': 1,
>               'then': 1,
>               "doesn't": 1,
>               'hurt.”': 1,
>               'M.': 1,
>               'Schulz': 1,
>               'food': 1,
>               '“Remember,': 1,
>               "we're": 1,
>               'madly': 1,
>               'love,': 1,
>               'so': 1,
>               "it's": 1,
>               'all': 1,
>               'kiss': 1,
>               'me': 1,
>               'anytime': 1,
>               'feel': 1,
>               'like': 1,
>               'Suzanne': 1,
>               'Collins': 1,
>               '“Some': 1,
>               'never': 1,
>               'go': 1,
>               'crazy.': 1,
>               'What': 1,
>               'truly': 1,
>               'horrible': 1,
>               'lives': 1,
>               'they': 1,
>               'lead.”': 1,
>               'Bukowski': 1,
>               'trouble': 1,
>               'having': 1,
>               'an': 1,
>               'open': 1,
>               'mind,': 1,
>               'course,': 1,
>               'will': 1,
>               'insist': 1,
>               'on': 1,
>               'coming': 1,
>               'along': 1,
>               'trying': 1,
>               'put': 1,
>               'things': 1,
>               'Terry': 1,
>               'Pratchett': 1,
>               'open-mind': 1,
>               'thinking': 1,
>               '“Think': 1,
>               'left': 1,
>               'low': 1,
>               'high.': 1,
>               'Oh,': 1,
>               'up': 1,
>               'if': 1,
>               'try!”': 1,
>               'Dr.': 1,
>               'Seuss': 1,
>               'philosophy': 1,
>               'reason': 1,
>               'talk': 1,
>               'myself': 1,
>               'because': 1,
>               'I’m': 1,
>               'one': 1,
>               'whose': 1,
>               'answers': 1,
>               'accept.”': 1,
>               'George': 1,
>               'Carlin': 1,
>               'insanity': 1,
>               'lies': 1,
>               'lying': 1,
>               'self-indulgence': 1,
>               'Next': 1,
>               '→': 1,
>               'Top': 1,
>               'Ten': 1,
>               'tags': 1,
>               'love': 1,
>               'inspirational': 1,
>               'life': 1,
>               'reading': 1,
>               'friendship': 1,
>               'friends': 1,
>               'by:': 1,
>               'GoodReads.com': 1,
>               'Made': 1,
>               '❤': 1,
>               'Scrapinghub': 1})