# Scrapy: catch responses with specific HTTP server codes

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

We have a pretty much standard Scrapy project (Scrapy 0.24).

I'd like to catch specific HTTP response codes, such as 200, 500, 502, 503, 504 etc.

Something like that:

```
class Spider(...):

    def parse(...):
        processes HTTP 200

    def parse_500(...):
        processes HTTP 500 errors

    def parse_502(...):
        processes HTTP 502 errors

    ...
```

How can we do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, Scrapy only handles responses with status codes `200`-`300`.

[Let Scrapy handle `500` and `502`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724730/how-to-get-the-scrapy-failure-urls):

```
class Spider(...):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [500, 502]
```

Then, in the `parse()` callback, check `response.status`:

```
def parse(response):
    if response.status == 500:
        # logic here
    elif response.status == 502:
        # logic here
```

Comment: assume there are several parse function in the spider. adding status condition in each parse function seems less graceful. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: [HttpErrorMiddleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror)