# How to handle connection or download error in Scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, twisted, scrapy

I am using the following to check for (internet) connection errors in my `spider.py`:

```py
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, errback=self.handle_error)

def handle_error(self, failure):
    if failure.check(DNSLookupError):   # or failure.check(UnknownHostError):
        request = failure.request
        self.logger.error('DNSLookupError on: %s', request.url)
        print("\nDNS Error! Please check your internet connection!\n")

    elif failure.check(HttpError):
        response = failure.value.response
        self.logger.error('HttpError on: %s', response.url)

    print('\nSpider closed because of Connection issues!\n')
    raise CloseSpider('Because of Connection issues!')
    ...
```

However, when the spider runs and the connection is down, I still get a **`Traceback (most recent call last):`** messages. I would like to get rid of this by handling the error and shutting down the spider properly.

The output I get is:

```
2018-10-11 12:52:15 [NewAds] ERROR: DNSLookupError on: https://x.com

DNS Error! Please check your internet connection!

2018-10-11 12:52:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://x.com>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1384, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 408, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 954, in startConnectionAttempts
    "no results for hostname lookup: {}".format(self._hostStr)

twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: x.com.
```

From this you can notice the following:

1. I am able to partially handle the (first?) `DNSLookupError` error, but...
2. shutting down the spider does not seem fast enough so the spider continue to try to download the URL, causing a different error (`ERROR: Error downloading`).
3. possibly causing a 2nd error: `twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError:`?

**How can I handle `[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading` and make sure the spider get shut down properly?**

(Or: *How can I check internet connection on spider startup?*)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have been trying to play nice with Scrapy, trying to exit 
gracefully when there is no internet connection or other error. The result? I could not get it to work properly. Instead I ended up just shutting down the entire interpreter and all it's obnoxious deferred children using **`os._exit(0)`**, like this:

```py
import socket
#from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
...
def check_connection(self):
    try:
        socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 443))
        return True
    except:
        pass
    return False

def start_requests(self):
    if not self.check_connection(): 
        print('Connection Lost! Please check your internet connection!', flush=True)
        os._exit(0)                     # Kill Everything
        #CloseSpider('Grace Me!')       # Close clean but expect deferred errors!
        #raise CloseSpider('No Grace')  # Raise Exception (w. Traceback)?!
    ...
```

**That did it!**

---

**NOTE**

I tried to use various internal methods to shutdown Scrapy, and handle the obnoxious:

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading
```

issue. This only (?) happens when you use: `raise CloseSpider('Because of Connection issues!')` among many other attempts. Again followed by a `twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError`, even though I have handled that in *my* code, it seem to appear out of nowhere. Obviously `raise` is the manual way to [always raise an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python). So instead use the `CloseSpider()` without it.

---

The issue at hand also seem to be a re-occurring issue in the Scrapy framework...and in fact the source code has some FIXME's [in there](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/scraper.py#L138). Even when I tried to apply things like:

```py
def stop(self):
    self.deferred = defer.Deferred()
    for name, signal in vars(signals).items():
        if not name.startswith('_'):
            disconnect_all(signal)
    self.deferred.callback(None)
```

and using these...

```
#self.stop()
#sys.exit()
#disconnect_all(signal, **kwargs)
#self.crawler.engine.close_spider(spider, 'cancelled')
#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner.stop()
#crawler.signals.stop()
```

PS. I would be great if the Scrapy devs could document how to best deal with such a simple case as a no internet-connection?

Comment: Great investigation. You have inspired me to try and also find an answer. 
One comment is I believe that ```disconnect_all(signal)``` will disconnect the listeners of that signal, but does not actually tell the spider to close

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may just have found an answer. To exit out of start_requests gracefully, `return []`. This is telling it there are no requests to process.

To close a spider, call the close() method on the spider:
self.close('reason')

```
import logging
import scrapy
import socket


class SpiderIndex(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    def check_connection(self):
        try:
            socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 443))
            return True
        except Exception:
            pass
        return False

    def start_requests(self):
        if not self.check_connection():
            print('Connection Lost! Please check your internet connection!', flush=True)
            self.close(self, 'Connection Lost!')
            return []

        # Continue as normal ...
        request = scrapy.Request(url='https://www.google.com', callback=self.parse)
        yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log(f'===TEST SPIDER: PARSE REQUEST======{response.url}===========', logging.INFO)
```

Addendum: For some strange reason, on one spider `self.close('reason')` worked while as on another I had to change it to `self.close(self, 'reason')`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue with twisted.defer trapping the exceptions after trying to closing the twisted connections which prevents the code shutting down gracefully.

So, eject the core I guess...

```
os._exit(0)
```