# calculating coverage of a scrapy webspider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing web spiders to scrap some products form websites using [scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy) framework in python.
I was wondering what's the best practices to calculate the coverage and missing items of the written spiders.

What i'm using right now is logging cases that's was unable to parse or raises exceptions.
As an example for that: when i expect a specific format for a price of a product or an address of a place and i find that my written Regular expressions doesn't match the scrapped strings. or when my `xpath` selectors for specific data returns nothing.

Sometimes also when products are listed in one page or multiple ones i use `curl` and `grep` to roughly calculate the number of products. but i was wondering if there's better practices to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common approach is, yes, to use [`logging`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html) to log the error and exit the callback by returning nothing.

Example (product price is required):

```
loader = ProductLoader(ProductItem(), response=response)
loader.add_xpath('price', '//span[@class="price"]/text()')
if not loader.get_output_value('price'):
    log.msg("Error fetching product price", level=log.ERROR)
    return
```

You can also use [signals](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html) to catch and log all kind of exceptions happened while crawling, see:

- [how to process all kinds of exception in a scrapy project, in errback and callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069128/how-to-process-all-kinds-of-exception-in-a-scrapy-project-in-errback-and-callba)

This basically follows the [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) principle when you let the spider fail and catch and process the error in a single, one particular place - a signal handler.

---

Other thoughts:

- you can even place the response urls and error tracebacks into a database for a following review - this is still "logging", but in a structured manner which can be more convenient to go through later
- a good idea might be to create custom exceptions to represent different crawling errors, for instance: `MissingRequiredFieldError`, `InvalidFieldFormatError` which you can raise in case crawled fields haven't passed validation.

Comment: i personally prefer EAFP style more, so this answer is a relief, but does that mean that if i scrap 20 detail from 1 web page my parse function with be full of 20 try and except clauses ?

Comment: @HadyElsahar nope, in case you have a `spider_error` signal handler, all the exceptions raised while crawling will be "available" in the handler. Having custom exceptions raised should ease the error analyzing and processing..

Comment: yes but i prefer handling each detail in try catch clauses alone in order for the spider to complete scraping the rest of the details if it failed to get [optional item]. , moreover for dedicated log messages of missed cases, which part actually failed.(for example getting the price text or parsing it )

Comment: given so, does it look ugly to have lots of try, except clauses with log messages all over your code ? or that is common in EAFP ?

Comment: @HadyElsahar I think it's pretty much ok if you want to have more control inside the callback and handling exceptions on a more "global" level is not an option.